# Rename columns of a data frame by searching column name

Tags: r

I am writing a wrapper to ggplot to produce multiple graphs based on various datasets. As I am passing the column names to the function, I need to rename the column names so that ggplot can understand the reference.

However, I am struggling with renaming of the columns of a data frame

here's a data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(col1=1:3,col2=3:5,col3=6:8)
```

here are my column names for search:

```
col1_search <- "col1"
col2_search <- "col2"
col3_search <- "col3"
```

and here are column names to replace:

```
col1_replace <- "new_col1"
col2_replace <- "new_col2"
col3_replace <- "new_col3"
```

when I search for column names, R sorts the column indexes and disregards the search location.

for example, when I run the following code, I expected the new headers to be new_col1, new_col2, and new_col3, instead the new column names are: new_col3, new_col2, and new_col1

```
colnames(df)[names(df) %in% c(col3_search,col2_search,col1_search)] <- c(col3_replace,col2_replace,col1_replace)
```

Does anyone have a solution where I can search for column names and replace them in that order?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand the need for this renaming.  You should look at `aes_string(...)` in `ggplot2`.  I think using that will avoid the need to rename columns within the function.

Comment: thanks, Justin. I will look into aes_string

Comment: you are absolutely right, Justin. That worked; no need to rename column names as I can directly pass string variables as arguments to `ggplot` using `aes_string`. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
require(plyr)
df <- data.frame(col2=1:3,col1=3:5,col3=6:8)
df <- rename(df, c("col1"="new_col1", "col2"="new_col2", "col3"="new_col3"))
df
```

And you can be creative in making that second argument to `rename` so that it is not so manual.

Comment: @Jared, I tried "being creative in making that second argument," but I kinda failed miserably. I tried `paste0('"', c("col1", "col2", "col3"), '"','=', '"',c("new_col1", "new_col2", "new_col3"), '"',collapse = ',')` I would appreciate if you--or anyone else--could advise me in how you would do it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

```
> names(df)[grep("^col", names(df))] <- 
                        paste("new", names(df)[grep("^col", names(df))], sep="_")
> names(df)
[1] "new_col1" "new_col2" "new_col3"
```

If you want to replace an ordered set of column names with an arbitrary character vector, then this should work:

```
names(df)[sapply(oldNames, grep, names(df) )] <- newNames
```

The `sapply`()-ed `grep` will give you the proper locations for the 'newNames' vector. I suppose you might want to make sure there are a complete set of matches if you were building this into a function.

Comment: thanks, Dwin. I had provided colnames just an example. Actually, my new column and old column names are different and do not have a pattern. Also, searching by names does not keep the order for replacing. I do not know the order of the columns; they could be anywhere. That is why in my example I am searching for `c(col3_search,col2_search,col1_search)`

Answer (score 2):

hmm, this might be way to complicated, but the first that come into my mind:

```
lookup <- data.frame(search = c(col3_search,col2_search,col1_search),
                     replace = c(col3_replace,col2_replace,col1_replace))

colnames(df) <- lookup$replace[match(lookup$search, colnames(df))]
```

Comment: I found that match function retains the order of matches, so this following code does what I want:     cols_to_search <- c("col3","col2","col1")
   cols_to_replace <- c("new_col3","new_col2","new_col1")
   match(cols_to_search, colnames(df))
   colnames(df)[match(cols_to_search, colnames(df))] <- cols_to_replace

Comment: I tried a `match` solution, too, but found that it fails when there are any `NA`'s in the match results.

Comment: @DWin: Yes this fails then, but in this lookup-table should be only valid names.

Answer (score 1):

I second @justin's aes_string suggestion.  But for future renaming you can try.

```
require(stringr)
df <- data.frame(col1=1:3,col2=3:5,col3=6:8)
oldNames <- c("col1", "col2", "col3")
newNames <- c("new_col1", "new_col2", "new_col3")
names(df) <- str_replace(string=names(df), pattern=oldNames, replacement=newNames)
```

Comment: You're right, the order matters for that, so see my next answer please.