# paste0-build an argument inside plyr:rename (now with update)

Tags: r, rename, paste, plyr

I'm working from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11367485/rename-columns-of-a-data-frame-by-searching-column-name/11379464#11379464) trying to optimize the second argument in the `plyr:rename`, as suggested by [Jared](https://stackoverflow.com/users/260533/jared).

In short *they* are renaming some columns in a data frame using `plyr` like this,

```
df <- data.frame(col1=1:3,col2=3:5,col3=6:8)
df
newNames <- c("new_col1", "new_col2", "new_col3")
oldNames <- names(df)

require(plyr)
df <- rename(df, c("col1"="new_col1", "col2"="new_col2", "col3"="new_col3"))
df
```

In passing [Jared](https://stackoverflow.com/users/260533/jared) writes '[a]nd you can be creative in making that second argument to rename so that it is not so manual.'

I've tried *being creative* like this,

```
df <- data.frame(col1=1:3,col2=3:5,col3=6:8)
df
secondArgument <- paste0('"', oldNames, '"','=', '"',newNames, '"',collapse = ',')
df <- rename(df, secondArgument)
df
```

But it does not work, can anyone help me automates this?

Thanks!

#### Update Sun Sep 9 11:55:42PM

I realized I should have been more specific in my question.

I'm using `plyr::rename` because I, in my real life example, have other variables and I don't always know the position of the variables I want to rename. I'll add an update to my question

My case look like this, but with 100+ variables

```
df2 <- data.frame(col1=1:3,col2=3:5,col3=6:8)
df2
df2 <- rename(df2, c("col1"="new_col1", "col3"="new_col3"))
df2

df2 <- data.frame(col1=1:3,col2=3:5,col3=6:8)
df2
newNames <- c("new_col1", "new_col3")
oldNames <- names(df[,c('col1', 'col3')])
secondArgument <- paste0('"', oldNames, '"','=', '"',newNames, '"',collapse = ',')
df2 <- rename(df2, secondArgument)
df2
```

Please add an comment if there is anything I need to clarify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution to modified question:

```
df2 <- data.frame(col1=1:3,col2=3:5,col3=6:8)
df2
newNames <- c("new_col1", "new_col3")
oldNames <- names(df2[,c('col1', 'col3')])
```

(Isn't `oldNames` equal to`c('col1','col3')` by definition?)

Solution with `plyr`:

```
secondArgument <- setNames(newNames,oldNames)
library(plyr)
df2 <- rename(df2, secondArgument)
df2
```

Or in base R you could do:

```
names(df2)[match(oldNames,names(df2))] <- newNames
```

Answer (score 3):

Set the names on `newNames` to the names from `oldNames`:

```
R> names(newNames) <- oldNames
R> newNames
      col1       col2       col3 
"new_col1" "new_col2" "new_col3" 
R> df <- rename(df, newNames)
R> df
  new_col1 new_col2 new_col3
1        1        3        6
2        2        4        7
3        3        5        8
```

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. I should have been more specific. I'm using `plyr::rename` because I, in my real life example, have other variables and I don't always know the position of the variables I want to rename. I'll add an update to my question.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich  and @learnr both have correct solution. The `replace` argument in `rename` is a *named character vector*. This is what you are referring to as the second argument. You have a *character vector* of new names and set the names of this vector to the *old name*, those you wish to replace.

Answer (score 2):

`plyr::rename` requires a named character vector, with new names as values, and old names as names.

This should work:

```
names(newNames) <- oldNames
df <- rename(df, newNames)
df
  new_col1 new_col2 new_col3
1        1        3        6
2        2        4        7
3        3        5        8
```

Comment: Thank you for responding to my question. I should have been more specific. I'm using `plyr::rename` because I, in my real life example, have other variables and I don't always know the position of the variables I want to rename. I'll add an update to my question.